# One Hot Encoding of Array with known Classes (Python)

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding

I would like to create an function (Python), which returns a one-hot-encoding of a 1D-Array.
Currently I implemented something like this, but this seems way to clunky and not clean at all:

```
def one_hot_encode(input_array, class_list):
    # returns a int representation of a class
    class_dict = {}
    for class_el in class_list:
        class_dict[class_el] = len(class_dict)

    for i, el in enumerate(input_array):
        if el in class_list:
            one_hot_vector = [0] * len(class_list)
            one_hot_vector[class_dict[el]] = 1
            input_array[i] = one_hot_vector
    return input_array

list_with_classes = ["A","A","B","C","A","B"]
one_hot_encode(list_with_classes, ("A", "B", "C")) # A,B,C are example classes
```

Is there a "better" way to implement this, with standard libs or just numpy? (I heard of Scikit-learn but I didn't figure out how to use it)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) in Scikit-learn. The interface is slightly different from yours though.